# C easy pointer example

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Could anyone explain me why result of a program is "5 3". I need short list of steps showing how the program works. Please, forgive me if my question is too simple, I'm just beginner. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float x = 4.5;
float y = 2;
float proc(float z, float *x)
{
 *x *= y;
 return z + *x;
}
int main()
{
 float x, y, *z;
 x = 2.5; y = -2; z = &x;
 y = proc(y, z);
 printf("%f %f\n", x, y);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain where you've got to so far and which statement you don't understand.

Comment: You can use a debugger and step line-by-line to see what's happening, or just add a printf after every line, to print out any variables that were changed by that line.

Comment: It may help if you change the names of variables so that the same identifier is not used for different purposes (e.g. there are three different `x`'s in this code)

Comment: Installing codeblocks and debugging the code would better help you understand what's going on in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
 float x, y, *z;
 x = 2.5; y = -2; z = &x;
 y = proc(y, z);  

 /*
  inside the proc function, you are passing -2 and the address of x in to proc.
  *x = *x * y // y = 2 which is the global variable defined earlier and *x = 2.5 which is the                  passed in variable.
  *x = 5 after the multiplication.
  z + *x = 3 will be returned and passed in to the variable y defined inside the main function.
  */
 printf("%f %f\n", x, y);
 return 0;
}
```